# How to open a connection with netty, and immediately send data to my connected host?

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to figure out how to open a connection with netty and send the server some data.

This is my code I'm attempting to get working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(); // (1)
        b.group(workerGroup); // (2)
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class); // (3)
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (4)
        b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new InboundHandler());
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new OutboundHandler());
            }
        });


        Channel channel = b.connect("localhost", 22000).channel();
        channel.write(true); //Lets send a boolean to test. 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

I've tried sending the data as well when my inboundhandler is registered. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the error message and/or stacktrace?

Comment: No error. Data just isn't getting sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add logging handler to your pipeline to debug your data exchange:

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ch.pipeline().addFirst(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new InboundHandler());
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new OutboundHandler());
}
```

You should add listener to react on connection complete event like this:

```
ChannelFuture cf = b.connect("localhost", 22000);

cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        if(future.isSuccess()) {
            //Here wrap your data into ByteBuf
            future.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.buffer().writeByte(5));
        } else {
            //Connection failed, add proper error handling !
            future.cause().printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
});
```

Confirmed that data was received:

`strace -e recvfrom nc -k  -l 22000`

```
09:16:18.222252 recvfrom(5, "\x05", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1
09:16:18.223916 recvfrom(5, "", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 0
```

Comment: Unless I am doing something wrong, this isn't working either.
Code:
http://pastebin.com/DxutrBH5 (No data is being sent either)

Comment: How are you sure that no data being sent? can you confirm with wireshark/tcpdump ?

Comment: Using netcat. I was able to do the same thing with regular java sockets. 
nc -l -p 22000

Comment: @UNDERGROUNDBTCHITMAN : you wrote : `Updated with code`, but I don;t see any changes in code you posted.